# How to Accurately Replicate Instagram's Custom Transition in UIKit

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I came across this [article](https://about.instagram.com/blog/engineering/on-building-a-fluid-user-interface) by Instagram and attempted to recreate their fluid navigation transition using `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning`. I've read various examples and have a good grasp of how custom transitions generally operate.

##### The Challenge

To clarify, let's refer to the following screenshots from Instagram:

| Keyframe 1 | Keyframe 2 | Keyframe 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [image: Messi1] | [image: Messi2] | [image: Messi3] |

The goal is to have the square image from `fromVC` overlay onto the `imageView` in `toVC`, aligning the two images exactly. Note that it should work regardless of the aspect ratio of `toVC.imageView`. At the same time, `windowView` should expand, revealing `toVC` until it reaches its final frame, resulting in a nice fluid transition.

##### My Attempt

My initial attempt didn't achieve the desired effect—`toVC` neither scales nor expands from the center (which is obvious because I didn't implement any handling for such cases). It just slides in from the right. This issue seems related to the auto layout of the snapshot view, which I haven't resolved.

[image: My Attempt]

##### My Code

```swift
private func performPresentTransition(using context: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {
    let containerView = context.containerView
    guard let fromVC = context.viewController(forKey: .from) as? ViewController,
          let originFrame,
          let toVC = context.viewController(forKey: .to) as? UINavigationController,
          let detailVC = toVC.topViewController as? PhotoDetailViewController
    else {
        return
    }
    guard let snapshot = toVC.view.snapshotView(afterScreenUpdates: true)
    else {
        return
    }

    let finalFrame = context.finalFrame(for: toVC)

    let windowView = UIView()
    containerView.addSubview(windowView)
    windowView.backgroundColor = .red
    windowView.layer.cornerRadius = 0
    windowView.clipsToBounds = true
    windowView.frame = originFrame

    windowView.addSubview(snapshot)
    snapshot.snp.makeConstraints { make in
        make.edges.equalToSuperview()
    }

    containerView.addSubview(toVC.view)
    toVC.view.isHidden = true

    snapshot.alpha = 0

    UIView.animate(withDuration: transitionDuration(using: context)) {
        snapshot.alpha = 1
        windowView.frame = finalFrame
        windowView.layer.cornerRadius = 30
    } completion: { _ in
        toVC.view.isHidden = false
        windowView.removeFromSuperview()
        context.completeTransition(!context.transitionWasCancelled)
    }

}
```

I'd like to know how to set the constraints to precisely mimic the behavior in the real app.

Also, any suggestions for replicating this Instagram animation are welcome. I'd prefer not to use third-party libraries.